# How can I disable the warnings generated by an inferred @NotNull/@Nullable annotation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is incorrectly inferring a method as `@NotNull`

```
// Incorrect inferred @NotNull annotation
// Generated with custom extension from proto
public java.lang.String getBoxedFoo() {
    return getOptionalFoo().orElse(null); // It warns here too
}

// Generated with custom extension from proto
public java.util.Optional<java.lang.String> getOptionalFoo() {
    if (hasFoo()) {
        return java.util.Optional.of(getFoo().getValue());
    } else {
        return java.util.Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

And therefore generating incorrect warnings when I have code such as

```
Optional.ofNullable(obj.getBoxedFoo()); // Passing a non-null argument to 'Optional'
```

Can I turn off such warnings caused by inferred annotations? I'd rather disable all warnings from inferred annotations via Preferences than have to add extra code to my codebase on each instance of a bad annotation inference by IntelliJ.

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3

Comment: The following inspection is responsible for the warning: Java | Probable bugs | Constant conditions & exceptions. It can be disabled. But the issue is not reproduced in v2020.3 for me. Can you please add the getOptionalFoo() method to the description?

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Added. Thanks for pointing out the inspection. Is there an option to disable it only for inferred `@NotNull` annotations? I'd prefer not to disable the entire inspection.

Comment: Do you have the inspection's option "treat non-annotated members and parameters as @Nullable" enabled? If I disabled it in v2020.3, inspection doesn't trigger.

Comment: I do not have that flag enabled. Inspection still triggers. The problem does not seem to be with the inspection, but the fact that the inferred annotation is wrong. If there's no way to fix or disable the inferred annotation, then it seems I have to just live with the warnings.

Comment: Please file a bug in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Thank you